# How to set a custom cursor at the launch of an OSX spritekit app?

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit, cursor

So I want to use a custom cursor in my spritekit game. I've only been able to get it to work by adding this to my first scene:

```
override func mouseEntered(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let myCursor: NSCursor = NSCursor(image: NSImage(named: "cursor")!, hotSpot: NSPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
    self.view?.addCursorRect(self.frame, cursor: myCursor)
}
```

However, this doesn't change the cursor to my custom one until I've clicked twice and moved the mouse. What I really want is to have the new cursor show up as soon as the app launches. Any ideas? Adding the cursor in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by putting your code into sprite kit's didMoveToView function:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)

    // Show custom mouse cursor
    let myCursor: NSCursor = NSCursor(image: NSImage(named: "cursor")!, hotSpot: NSPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
    self.view!.addCursorRect(self.frame, cursor: myCursor)
}
```